# Please help me to edit some javascript problems using javascript koans?

Tags: javascript

Hey Guys I am  learning javascript via Javascript koans, and I am trying to correct the errors in the following (Thanks for any guidance):

```
module("About Asserts (topics/about_asserts.js)");

test("ok", function() {
ok(_ ===true, 'what will satisfy the ok assertion?');
});

 test("not", function() {
not(__, 'what is a false value?');
 } );

  test("equals", function() {
equals( __,1+1  'what will satisfy the equals assertion?');
 });
```

this is was I attempted but still the code did not run

```
  module("About Asserts (topics/about_asserts.js)");

 test("ok", function() {
ok(true, 'what will satisfy the ok assertion?');
 });

 test("not", function() {
not(false, 'what is a false value?');
 });

test("equals", function() {
equals( 2==,1+ 1 'what will satisfy the equals assertion?');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going wrong in the formatting of your answers. Only replace the underlined parts and leave the rest of it entirely alone. It's a little bit confusing at first, but you'll get a hang of it pretty quickly.

The program is likely looking for the following:

```
test("ok", function() {
ok(true===true, 'what will satisfy the ok assertion?');
});

test("not", function() {
not(false, 'what is a false value?');
} );

test("equals", function() {
equals(2,1+1  'what will satisfy the equals assertion?');
});
```